# C# for loop to count through array not working

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, console.writeline

I am trying to make a C# for loop that will loop through an array of items and print the first date of the user. Below is the code for the array (which i think is correct).

```
string[,] arrHolidays = new string[2, 3];
arrHolidays[0, 0] = "10/05/2015";
arrHolidays[0, 1] = "15/05/2015";
arrHolidays[0, 2] = "Danny";
arrHolidays[1, 0] = "20/05/2015";
arrHolidays[1, 1] = "22/05/2015";
arrHolidays[1, 2] = "Kieran";
```

Below is the code for the For loop (which is throwing the error)

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrHolidays.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arrHolidays[i, 0]);            
}
```

Index out of range exception was unhandled. this is the error I am recieving. When it throws the error and I check the value of 1 it is 2 if this is any help in resolving it.
What I am expecting to see is this in the console app:

`10/05/2015
20/05/2015`

INB4 I have hardly any c# experience this is my first project, so please explain any help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is IndexOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Maybe the three down-voters on this question could explain what they think is wrong with it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must use `GetLength` method, not the `Length` property.

The `Length` property for a multi-dimensional array returns the total count of all the items in the array. The `GetLength` method returns the number of size of a given dimension *(where dimension is specified as a **zero-based** index).*

So, `arrHolidays.Length` will return 6.

Change `for` loop to:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < arrHolidays.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
        Console.WriteLine(arrHolidays[i, 0]);
  }
```

Comment: +1, but still a small remark : things would be easier if the OP is using objects to save up his data.

Comment: yes debugging it does return six, which is every item. how would i make it return only the section i want the `[i,0]`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev it means before anyone says anything i know its an easy problem i'm just new to C# so please explain responses

Comment: @Kieranmv95 Not any problem. I will be glad to help you. Just comment here exactly what you want from me to explain.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev
your method works perfect, but when i try to implement the same thing for the other set of dates n a seperate for i get the error again :(.
`for (int i = 0; i < arrHolidays.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EndDate" + arrHolidays[i, 1]);
            }`

This **should** return the second set of dates i thought

Comment: @Kieranmv95 Because `arrHolidays.GetLength(1)` returns 3. Your array's is 2x3. And there is not exist arrHolidays[2,1];
You must write:
 `for (int i = 0; i < arrHolidays.GetLength(0); i++){Console.WriteLine(arrHolidays[i, 1]);}`

Comment: @Kieranmv95 )) It can happen to anyone. I am glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.GetLength(int dimension)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your case, you want to get the length of the first dimension, so `arrHolidays.GetLength(0)`.